# AXI SPI of MicroBlaze connected to SD card

Tags: fpga, spi, microblaze

I would like to connect SPI IP core of microblaze on custom board but I have some problem.
I need 100-400 KHZ clock but the system clk is 100MHz and SPI Clock is 6.25 MHz.
Is it necessary to reduce clk frequency for initialization?

I just send CMD0 to reset,I would like to check the write and read buffer to see tranfering of command is correct,but I couldn't get a correct result.

IS anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to reduce clk frequency for initialization?

Yes. SD cards come up in open drain mode - you also need a pullup. This resistor limits the answer speed of the card until it switches into SPI mode fully.

Comment: How I can reduce the clk frequency?

Comment: Use a Clock divider maybe...?

Answer (score 0):

I did not use microblaze, but the idea is that you should be able to intialize/set up parameters of your SPI block. This will generate your output clock. Otherwise, you need to provide a desired clock to the SPI block. If microblaze dos not generate output clock, you can create one using Clock wizard block.